# Create chart at the same time c#

Tags: c#, charts, graphic

i want to do some chart at the same time. I did it, only i choose parameters in combobox and after click on button and then create graphic. Now i need save some parameters and after click on button create two, three  graphic. How do this ? I use MS Chart, where input date from datagridview.

```
private void graph2()
    {
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[2].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[3].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;

        if (metroComboBox1.Text == "Name 1")
        {
            //chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;



            for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid2.Rows)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    Int32.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out x);

                    DateTime dt;


                    DateTime.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dt);

                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

                    if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Text 1")
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
                    }
                    if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Text 2")
                    {
                        chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Green;
                    }
                    //chart1.Series[0].Points[5].Color = Color.Blue;
                    //Console.WriteLine(chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        if (metroComboBox1.Text == "Name 2")
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid2.Rows)
                {
                    int x = 0;
                    Int32.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out x);

                    DateTime dt;


                    DateTime.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dt);

                    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                    if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Text1")
                    {
                        chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Red;
                    }
                    if (metroComboBox3.Text == "text2")
                    {
                        chart1.Series[1].Color = Color.Green;
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine(chart1.Series[00].Points.AddXY(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
```

........

Comment: You need to create a new chart for each graphic you want.

Comment: Or add ChartAreas. It would help to see an image of the desired result. As it is the question is rather unclear!

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger, no, need use one chart where will be many graphics.

Comment: Ok - I misunderstood graphics to mean charts. So you need to add new series. Each time you want new graphics, go through the process you did to add the first series again, but name the series something different. No - sorry - series is a collection. Go through the creation process again and add it to series so you have series[0] series[1] series[2] - one for each graphic

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger, i use series for enter some graphics. But need this 5 graphics output when click on one button

Comment: That's ok. Can you share your first graphic code and tell me the name of your button?

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger add code, Plz see up

Comment: Ok - see my answer below

Comment: Please comment below my answer from now on

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void graph2()
    {
        chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[1].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[2].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        chart1.Series[3].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
        setChart();
    }

    private void setChart()
    {
        switch (metroComboBox1.SelectedText.ToString())
        {
            case "Name 1":
                finalizeChart();
                break;
            case "Name 2":
                finalizeChart();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void finalizeChart()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < metroGrid2.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
                                int x = 0;
                Int32.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(), out x);

                DateTime dt;


                DateTime.TryParse(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dt);

                chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

                if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Text 1")
                {
                    chart1.Series[i].Color = Color.Red;
                }
                if (metroComboBox3.Text == "Text 2")
                {
                    chart1.Series[i].Color = Color.Green;
                }
                //chart1.Series[0].Points[5].Color = Color.Blue;
                //Console.WriteLine(chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't see any difference between when metroComboBox.SelectedText = "Name 1" and when it is "Name 2" I think this may be a cut/paste issue so I left room for making the processing different. What should be different between name 1 and name 2?

Comment: Error = Index out of range. The index must be a positive number, and it should not exceed the size of the collection. In this line:                         chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), metroGrid2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());

Comment: name 1 and name 2 are comboBox.Text

Comment: Ok - we need to look at what you're trying to do. Do you want a different graphic for every row in the table? Because that's how you have it set up. Forget the technical stuff for now and tell me what you are trying to do.